# Can't get gettext working in PHP, Linux

Tags: php, gettext

I've been struggling with Gettext now for ages and just can't get it to work. I would be forever grateful if someone could help me with this... I have looked for solutions and tried several variants but nothing is working for me.

I have created the following file structure:

> /var/www/battlestox/battlestox.com/sites/battlestox/www/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGE/messages.po
> /var/www/battlestox/battlestox.com/sites/battlestox/www/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGE/messages.mo

the data in the .po file is simply:

> msgid ""
>
> msgstr ""
>
> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
>
> "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
>
> msgid "qwerty"
>
> msgstr "The Translator works!"

The php file hase the following code:

```
putenv("LANG=de_DE.UTF-8");
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'de_DE.UTF-8');
bindtextdomain('messages', 'locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('messages');

echo gettext("qwerty");
echo _("qwerty");
```

output: qwertyqwerty - so no translation happening.
when I echo bindtextdomain('messages', 'locale'); I get:

> /var/www/battlestox/battlestox.com/sites/battlestox/www/locale

so I believe it's pointing to the correct location..

I have checked that gettext is installed in php and locales on the server are available..

:locale -a

> de_DE
>
> de_DE.iso88591
>
> de_DE.iso885915@euro
>
> de_DE.utf8
>
> de_DE@euro

I'm running PHP 5.2, Apache 2.2.3, CentOS

Please be gentle, I am very basic on linux..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: PS I've obviously compiled the .po file to make it the corresponding mo file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your .mo directory should be /var/www/..blah../locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES That's LC_MESSAGES, plural.

Also as John says, your locale name doesn't look quite right.

If you change the .mo file you need to restart apache. Have you done this?

Comment: AHHH! You're a genius.. Changing the name to LC_MESSAGES and restarting Apache sorted it!

Thank you so much - I've literally been bashing my head on the desk for days over this!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the exact locale name reported by `locale -a`. e.g. `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'de_DE.utf8');`

Comment: putenv("LANG=de_DE.utf8");
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'de_DE.utf8');

tried changing to the above but no joy...

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention. It turns out that English was the only supported language on the server I'm working with (CentOS/RHEL). I installed the appropriate [langpack](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/using-langpacks_configuring-basic-system-settings) and then `gettext` began to work perfectly.